# Problems with Keychain on Macbook Air

Tags: macbook-pro, keychain

I was having problems on my Macbook, getting my VPN service to start properly, and was they suggested that I create new Keychain and import settings into new Keychain. I did that, and now I am getting this constant pop-up message, saying autosd needs me to input my Keychain password.

Any ideas what is happening, [image]how to fix this issue and stop the messages?

Comment: so you want to leave the keychain permanently unlocked ?

Comment: check this out https://support.apple.com/en-us/HT201609